# What do prefixes like byte_ or off_ mean before a hex value?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm going through some code examples, and I saw the following line:

```
LDR R0, =(byte_1F30B65 - 0x756F70)
```

I can't seem to understand what the `byte_` means before the Hex number.
I checked around and found some more, for example

```
DCD unk_1944AA0

DCD off_1E78280
```

Can anyone explain what do these mean?

Note: This code is decompiled, it is not the original code.

Comment: What architecture, assembler, and platform is this?

Comment: @fuz: It's ARM.  You can tell from the `LDR R0, =numeric_constant` pseudo-instruction.

Comment: @fuz As Peter said, It's ARM. Also it's KEIL

Comment: They appear to be simply auto-generated identifier names.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't like guessing because there is always a chance that I guess wrong and waste my time writing an answer that doesn't apply.  People must state what architecture, platform, and assembler they are programming for.

Comment: @fuz: agreed.  It's definitely good that we have confirmation from the OP, and it shouldn't have been left out in the first place.  (But DCD was also consistent with ARM.)  And for this question, the answer will be pretty generic, like \@500 said these are just label/symbol names made up by a disassembler.

Comment: what happened when you tried the various combinations and disassembled to see what the assembler produced?  Does it make a difference in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are labels automatically generated by IDA or some other disassembler following IDA's convention for naming automatically generated labels.  The `byte_` prefix indicates that IDA believes a one byte variable is at the location the label refers to, the `off_` prefix indicates that the IDA believes a pointer variable is at the label's location, and the `ukn_` prefix means IDA doesn't know what's there.  The hexadecimal number is the address the label refers to.

The `off_` prefix comes from x86 assembly where all addresses have an offset and segment part. The variable at the location of an `off_` label would only contain the offset portion of an address. In 32-bit and 64-bit x86 assembly however it's generally safe to assume that the offset is relative to a "flat" segment that covers entire 32-bit or 64-bit address space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes I was using IDA, I forgot to mention that. Just to make sure I understand, these prefixes aren't related to the value, right? Meaning, they are just "guesses" what type the location holds.

Comment: @Lolization  IDA can't actually know what variables the program is using and what they're used for, it can only make inferences based on how it accesses memory. So if it uses byte sized load and store instructions to access a given location memory, it assumes it's a byte sized variable being accessed.  But it could be just part of string, or some other kind of larger object.